# Como enviar imagem dinâmica no corpo do email com VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel-vba

Criei uma macro para envio de imagens diferentes no corpo do email para pessoas diferentes. O problema é que não estou conseguindo deixar a imagem dinâmica no corpo do email. Ele está anexando certo, cada imagem a seu respectivo email. O problema é quando peço para deixar visível a imagem não abre, ficando em branco ou com erro.
Segue código que estou usando:

```
Function Saudacao() As String
    Dim hora As Date
    
    hora = Format(Now, "HH:MM:SS")
    
    Select Case hora
        Case "00:00:00" To "11:59:59"
            Saudacao = "Bom dia!"
        Case "12:00:00" To "17:59:59"
            Saudacao = "Boa Tarde!"
        Case Else
             Saudacao = "Boa Noite!"
    End Select
End Function

Sub Enviar_Email()
On Error GoTo TRATAR_ERRO

Range("A5").Activate
Assunto = Range("R1").Value
Mensagem = Range("R3").Value

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
    
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@empresa.com.br" 
        .Display
        .To = ActiveCell.Value
        .CC = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Assunto & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        .Attachments.Add ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value, , 1

        .HTMLBody = "<BR>" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ", " & Saudacao & "<BR><BR>" & Mensagem & "<BR><BR>" & "<img src='ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value'>" & "<BR>" & "Att," & "<BR>" & .HTMLBody
                       
        .Send

    End With

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Activate


    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
Loop
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "E-mails enviados com sucesso!", bvinformation, "Ok"
Exit Sub


TRATAR_ERRO:
Dim sErro As String
    sErro = Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    MsgBox sErro, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Enviar_email"

End Sub
```

Comment: Tentei fazer isso no powershell e também não consegui, só consegui colocar imagem no corpo do e-mail quando a refiro como link em formato HTML, espero que alguém poste a reposta.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, Talita!

Isso é uma intuição comum.
Eu adiciono a imagem como Attachment e depois coloco no corpo IMG SRC pegando do mesmo lugar no computador e fazendo o HTML renderizar.

O problema é que o e-mail não funciona exatamente assim.
Quando você tem uma imagem já no attachment para ir embutida  (embeded) precisa usar a tag CID:nomedaimagem.jpg/png (sem referência de diretório).

Logo:

```
... & "<img src='CID:" & Trim(Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value, instrrev(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value, "\")+1, 2000)) &  "'>" & "<BR>" & "Att
```

Essa parte do MID + InstrRev é pra excluir o caminho absoluto (c:\users...), supondo eu que está assim.

Se não estiver, ou quiser tratar basta colocar CID:imagem.png que está resolvido também